# How to navigate without localization

Tags: gazebo, navigation, odometry, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're using **turtlebot_gazebo** now and every time we **navigate**, it uses **amcl**. However, in our task,robot just needs to **avoid the obstacles and follow the target person in a small range of view**. In short, we want to modify or some way to **navigate without localization**. I suspect it is sth related to the tf and move_base but not quite clear what to do. Can it be easily fulfilled? What should we do? *Many Thanks!*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201806/how-to-navigate-without-localization/) by [sc071139](https://answers.ros.org/users/21489/sc071139/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to navigate without localisation, then disable your localisation node and publish a static transform between your /map and /odom frame. Amcl or some other localisation will usually provide this transform. This means that your robot will now only be as accurate as its odometry.

The global planner and local planner should still work in move base in the default costmap frame_id of /map.

You could alternatively try changing the costmap frame id to /odom which may achieve the same thing but I haven't tried this myself.

cheers

Peter

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0